# Eclipse: set shortcut for "Open With -> Java Editor" and "Open With -> System Editor" and switch to Package Explorer via keyboard

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

I find myself often switching between opening a file as "Open With -> Java Editor"
and "Open With -> System Editor". Is there a way I can assign a keyboard shortcut
to these actions in eclipse. Also, is there a keyboard shortcut to shift the window
focus from the java editor to the package explorer in eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To switch from an Editor to "Package Explorer" you can use Ctrl+F7 (or Cmd+F7 on Mac) which will cycle through all the open Views in Perspective.

As far as "Open With" goes, I was not able to find a way to bind these actions to a keys.

If you press Ctrl+Shift+L (Cmd+Shift+L on Mac) twice, Eclipse opens the "Keys" preference page, on which you can inspect all the commands to which you can bind your Shortcuts.